# Is the .htaccess stopping this jQuery from running and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, .htaccess

Good Afternoon,

I have a Joomla! template that keeps throwing up a pop up in browser reading only the word "here" like this [Screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35732749/Screen%20shot%202012-02-24%20at%2014.40.53.png)

Someone pointed me in the direction of the .htaccess file doing this so I checked the code in there...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /development/SWE/BRANDNAMEREMOVED

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
<Files ~ "\.xml$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files

# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

And the piece of jQuery that is causing the message to arise is in the browser is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $.fn.parallaxSlider = function(options) {
                var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.parallaxSlider.defaults, options);
                return this.each(function() {
                    var $pxs_container  = $(this),
                    o               = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $pxs_container.data()) : opts;

                    //the main slider
                    var $pxs_slider     = $('.pxs_slider',$pxs_container),
                    //the elements in the slider
                    $elems          = $pxs_slider.children(),
                    //total number of elements
                    total_elems     = $elems.length,
                    //the navigation buttons
                    $pxs_next       = $('.pxs_next',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_prev       = $('.pxs_prev',$pxs_container),
                    //the bg images
                    $pxs_bg1        = $('.pxs_bg1',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_bg2        = $('.pxs_bg2',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_bg3        = $('.pxs_bg3',$pxs_container),
                    //current image
                    current         = 0,
                    //the thumbs container
                    $pxs_thumbnails = $('.pxs_thumbnails',$pxs_container),
                    //the thumbs
                    $thumbs         = $pxs_thumbnails.children(),
                    //the interval for the autoplay mode
                    slideshow,
                    //the loading image
                    $pxs_loading    = $('.pxs_loading',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_slider_wrapper = $('.pxs_slider_wrapper',$pxs_container);

                    //first preload all the images
                    var loaded      = 0,
                    $images     = $pxs_slider_wrapper.find('img');

                    $images.each(function(){
                        var $img    = $(this);
                        $('<img/>').load(function(){
                            ++loaded;
                            if(loaded   == total_elems*2){
                                $pxs_loading.hide();
                                $pxs_slider_wrapper.show();

                                //one images width (assuming all images have the same sizes)
                                var one_image_w     = $pxs_slider.find('img:first').width();

                                /*
                                need to set width of the slider,
                                of each one of its elements, and of the
                                navigation buttons
                                 */
                                setWidths($pxs_slider,
                                $elems,
                                total_elems,
                                $pxs_bg1,
                                $pxs_bg2,
                                $pxs_bg3,
                                one_image_w,
                                $pxs_next,
                                $pxs_prev);

                                //make the first thumb be selected
                                highlight($thumbs.eq(0));

                                //slide when clicking the navigation buttons
                                $pxs_next.bind('click',function(){
                                    ++current;
                                    if(current >= total_elems)
                                        if(o.circular)
                                            current = 0;
                                    else{
                                        --current;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    highlight($thumbs.eq(current));
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });
                                $pxs_prev.bind('click',function(){
                                    --current;
                                    if(current < 0)
                                        if(o.circular)
                                            current = total_elems - 1;
                                    else{
                                        ++current;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    highlight($thumbs.eq(current));
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });

                                /*
                                clicking a thumb will slide to the respective image
                                 */
                                $thumbs.bind('click',function(){
                                    var $thumb  = $(this);
                                    highlight($thumb);
                                    //if autoplay interrupt when user clicks
                                    if(o.auto)
                                        clearInterval(slideshow);
                                    current     = $thumb.index();
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });



                                /*
                                activate the autoplay mode if
                                that option was specified
                                 */
                                if(o.auto != 0){
                                    o.circular  = true;
                                    slideshow   = setInterval(function(){
                                        $pxs_next.trigger('click');
                                    },o.auto);
                                }

                                /*
                                when resizing the window,
                                we need to recalculate the widths of the
                                slider elements, based on the new windows width.
                                we need to slide again to the current one,
                                since the left of the slider is no longer correct
                                 */
                                $(window).resize(function(){
                                    w_w = $(window).width();
                                    setWidths($pxs_slider,$elems,total_elems,$pxs_bg1,$pxs_bg2,$pxs_bg3,one_image_w,$pxs_next,$pxs_prev);
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    1,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });

                            }
                        }).error(function(){
                            alert('here')
                        }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
                    });



                });
            };

            //the current windows width
            var w_w             = $(window).width();

            var slide           = function(current,
            $pxs_slider,
            $pxs_bg3,
            $pxs_bg2,
            $pxs_bg1,
            speed,
            easing,
            easingBg){
                var slide_to    = parseInt(-w_w * current);
                $pxs_slider.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to + 'px'
                },speed, easing);
                $pxs_bg3.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to/2 + 'px'
                },speed, easingBg);
                $pxs_bg2.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to/4 + 'px'
                },speed, easingBg);
                $pxs_bg1.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to/8 + 'px'
                },speed, easingBg);
            }

            var highlight       = function($elem){
                $elem.siblings().removeClass('selected');
                $elem.addClass('selected');
            }

            var setWidths       = function($pxs_slider,
            $elems,
            total_elems,
            $pxs_bg1,
            $pxs_bg2,
            $pxs_bg3,
            one_image_w,
            $pxs_next,
            $pxs_prev){
                /*
                the width of the slider is the windows width
                times the total number of elements in the slider
                 */
                var pxs_slider_w    = w_w * total_elems;
                $pxs_slider.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');
                //each element will have a width = windows width
                $elems.width(w_w + 'px');
                /*
                we also set the width of each bg image div.
                The value is the same calculated for the pxs_slider
                 */
                $pxs_bg1.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');
                $pxs_bg2.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');
                $pxs_bg3.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');

            }

            $.fn.parallaxSlider.defaults = {
                auto            : 0,    //how many seconds to periodically slide the content.
                                        //If set to 0 then autoplay is turned off.
                speed           : 1000,//speed of each slide animation
                easing          : 'jswing',//easing effect for the slide animation
                easingBg        : 'jswing',//easing effect for the background animation
                circular        : true,//circular slider
                thumbRotation   : true//the thumbs will be randomly rotated
            };
            //easeInOutExpo,easeInBack

        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? I get the feeling i'm staring right at it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alert('here')` is coming from the error handler on your `$('<img/>').load(fn...)`.

If you check in the console you will see exactly what error is ocurring.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
.error(function(){
    alert('here')
}).
```

To this:

```
.error(function(data, handler){
    console.log(data);
}).
```

That should give you some more meaningful error handling.

Answer (score 1):

There alert is created by the error-callback of your load function, on this line:

```
.error(function(){
    alert('here')
}
```

So apparently some of your load-requests fail, try to log the error to the console to get some more input on what might be going wrong in the request.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess has nothing to do with javascript execution, .htaccess is serverside and javascript client side.
I can see clearly an alert('here') in your code which you can comment out (only if doesn't affect your code or if you don't know the code) but if you want to fix it you should start debugging to see what's happening.